# Issue With *Only One* Animation Block (UILabel) Using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, autolayout, constraints

I am using AutoLayout and am animating various constraint changes without any issue.  However, there is one UILabel in the VC that simply will not animate.  My desired animation is a wipe-like effect.  I have since setup a timer, as per rdelmar's suggestion as a UILabel does not support animating constraints, and am getting the effect I desire for labels that are only one line long.  However, labels that are multiple lines are not producing a wipe-like effect, but rather the characters are wrapping and as the label's width is increased.  Below is how I have the label's constraints setup.

```
- (void)initializeLabelWithMessage:(NSDictionary *)message {
    meaningLabel.text = [messagingSubMethods meaningStringForLabelFromMessage:message];        
    meaningLabel.numberOfLines = _expectedNumberOfLines;

    float meaningLabelHeight;
    if (_expectedNumberOfLines == 2) {
        meaningLabelHeight = 32;
    } else if (_expectedNumberOfLines == 3) {
        meaningLabelHeight = 48;
    } else {
        meaningLabelHeight = 18;
    }

    _meaningWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
    _meaningHeightConstraint.constant = meaningLabelHeight;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

[image]

Below is my approach to 'animating' the label's width, giving me the effect I wish for only if the numberOfLines is 1.

```
- (void)startMeaningAnimationTimer {
    _meaningAnimationTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(increaseMeaningLabelWidth) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:_meaningAnimationTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_meaningAnimationTimer fire];
}

- (void)increaseMeaningLabelWidth {
    if (_meaningWidthConstraint.constant < _expectedMeaningWidth) {
        _meaningWidthConstraint.constant = _meaningWidthConstraint.constant + 1;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } else
        [self stopMeaningAnimationTimer];
}
```

The below code is what I added after Rob's suggestion.  The first was my initial attempt to integrate his code with mine.  The second attempt was seeing if I could 'copy and paste' his code in.

```
- (void)attempt1 {
    _meaning1WidthConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _meaningWidthConstraint.constant = expectedWidth;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        _meaning1WidthConstraint.constant = expectedWidth;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)attempt2 {
    _meaning1WidthConstraint.constant = [meaningLabel1 sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(expectedWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)].width;
    [meaningLabel1 layoutIfNeeded];

    // Now animate the container.
    _meaning1WidthConstraint.constant = _meaning1WidthConstraint.constant;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [meaningLabel1.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Do other labels work properly? If I remember correctly, you can't animate labels this way. You need to use a timer instead.

Comment: No, the other elements I am animating are not labels.  I tried the timer like you suggested and it looks really funky!  As the width increases, the label readjusts the characters.  Now I am trying to figure out a way to have it reveal like a static image rather than a resizing label.  I did get the effect I wanted in a previous project by animating a UILabel frame.  Not sure if there is a way to get the same effect easily with AutoLayout though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "readjusts the characters". I don't see that when I do it. What effect are you trying to get? Do you want the text size to change or not?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, should have been more specific.  When the label is only one line, it is exactly the effect I would like; the label has a wipe-like animation as it reveals its contents.  When it is more than one line, however, the characters are constantly reorganizing themselves via the line break.  I could create a new label, but keeping one label with a line break in which the characters not not reorder during the 'animation' would certainly be best.

Comment: Edit your question to include details of how the label and its constraints are set up.  Post the code if it's code.  Otherwise post screen shots of the Attributes and Size inspectors for the label.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think animating with an `NSTimer` is a good approach.

I guess you want something like this:

[image: example]

I put the label inside a container view and I animate the container view's frame (via constraints).  Here's my scene outline:

[image: scene outline]

So, I have width and height constraints on the label, and I also have width and height constraints on the container view (the label's superview).  The sizes of these width and height constraints don't really matter, because I will set them in code.  I have constraints on the label pinning it to the top and left edges of the container.  I have constraints on the container centering it in its parent (the root view of the scene).

I have the container's “Clip Subviews” checked (in the attributes inspector), and I have the label's view mode set to “Top Left” (the default is “Left”).

In my view controller, I have outlets to the label, to the label's width and height constraints, and to the container's width and height constraints:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelContainerWidthConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelContainerHeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelWidthConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeightConstraint;
@end
```

When the view loads, I need to set up the constraints for the small size, so I pretend the small button was tapped, but I disable animation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [self smallButtonWasTapped:self];
    }];
}
```

When the “Small” button is tapped, I want to animate the container's frame.  I have a hardcoded width, but I'd like to figure out the height programmatically by asking the label how tall it would be if it were one line tall.  However, I don't really want it to be one line tall, so I change its `numberOfLines` temporarily:

```
- (IBAction)smallButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    self.labelContainerWidthConstraint.constant = 150;
    self.label.numberOfLines = 1;
    self.labelContainerHeightConstraint.constant = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Then I perform layout inside an animation block so the layout change will be animated:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [self.label.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }
```

Note that I haven't modified the label's constraints, so it will keep the same frame and content.  It won't reflow, which seemed to be your chief complaint.

When the animation is finished, I'd like to show an ellipsis to represent the no-longer-visible content, so in the completion block, I **do** change the label's `lineBreakMode` and constraints:

```
      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
            self.labelWidthConstraint.constant = self.labelContainerWidthConstraint.constant;
            self.labelHeightConstraint.constant = self.labelContainerHeightConstraint.constant;
        }
    }];
```

But I don't animate the layout, so the label will instantly change to showing the ellipsis.

When the “Big” button is tapped, I want to immediately get rid of the ellipsis and make the label full-sized so the user won't see missing or reflowing text:

```
- (IBAction)bigButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    // First, get rid of the ellipsis and resize the label without animation.
    self.label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.labelWidthConstraint.constant = 300;
    self.labelHeightConstraint.constant = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.labelWidthConstraint.constant, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;
    [self.label layoutIfNeeded];
```

Then I can set the container's constraints to match the label's, and animate the layout:

```
    // Now animate the container.
    self.labelContainerWidthConstraint.constant = self.labelWidthConstraint.constant;
    self.labelContainerHeightConstraint.constant = self.labelHeightConstraint.constant;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        [self.label.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

I've uploaded my project [to this github repository](https://github.com/mayoff/multiline-UILabel-expose-without-reflow).

Comment: Wow, you are a very kind man!  I bet you have directly impacted the lives of many coders this way.  We have circled back to the above (sorry for the 2 week delay) and yes, the timer does look a little funny.  It is also a bit buggy/unstable.  I did as you said and placed the labels in a UIView as a container.  I tried manipulating the code a few different ways, but the label still will not 'animate.'  Instead, the closest I can come is the UIView animating properly, but the label is full sized and exceeds the width of its container.

Comment: Also just inserted the code I tried using your response above.